# Does "all" in iterate through the rest of the array if the first element is False?

Tags: python

I think `all` will skip the rest of an array of boolean values as soon as it encounters a `False`. Can anyone please confirm the same?

`array = [False, True, True ...(1000s of values of True)]`

`all(array)`

The time complexity to run the above set of statements would/should be constant, i.e. O(1), right?

Comment: It will skip the rest of the list. `any` and `all` are evaluated _lazily_. But _creating_ the list is still O(n).

Comment: "Can anyone please confirm the same?" The way to do this is to *read the documentation*. "The time complexity to run the above set of statements would/should be constant, i.e. O(1), right?" No, because you have to *create the list* before you can use `all`.

Answer (score 3):

`all` will stop. Since it works with *any* arbitrary iterable, you can see this using a list iterator.

```
>>> i = iter([False, True, True])
>>> all(i)
False
>>> list(i)
[True, True]
```

If `all` hadn't stopped, `list(i)` would have returned the empty list.

Another way to see this is to see that `all` will terminate when given an infinite sequence.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> all(repeat(False))
False
```

`all(repeat(True))`, on the other hand, will never terminate.